# How to install Tachograph (a monitoring tool of MonetDB Jul2015 release) in Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: monetdb

I have installed the latest Jul2015 release, and I would like to use the
latest tools tachograph to determine the progress of query execution.

According to https://www.monetdb.org/Documentation/Manuals/MonetDB/Profiler/tachograph,
Tachograph is available as of Jul2015 release

But I do not know how to install it. My system is ubuntu 14.04.

I have tried to use *sudo apt-get install monetdb-tools* but failed to
locate the package *monetdb-tools*.

Any suggestion would be helpful. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Tachograph is in `monetdb-client-tools`. Also, see https://dev.monetdb.org/downloads/deb/ for instructions on how to add the MonetDB repository to your system.